# Не добавляется окно информации

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Есть интервал, в котором элементы массива отображаются на карте. Хочу к отображаемым маркерам добавить окно информации. Но почему-то метод не срабатывает.Обьявляю массив наполняю его через цикл ...Но ничего не происходит

```
var Cicle = setInterval(function() {
  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];


  var markers = [];
  var infowindow = [];
  var num_markers = locations.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: locations[i][1],
        lng: locations[i][2]
      },
      map: map
    });


  };

  for (var i = 0; i < num_markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setPosition(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

    //Данный метод добавения окна с текстом не работает*
    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow[i].setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow[i].open(map, marker[i]);

  }

}, 15000);
Cicle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InfoWindow` не нужно создавать несколько раз.
Точно такой же вопрос создавали на en stackoverflow.
[Multiple “InfoWindow” for array of “markers” on Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071534/6030504)
Загуглил за минуту.

> Прежде чем задавать вопрос, лучше потратить минуту на гугл, это быстрей.

Comment: Спасибо я На самом деле сам нашел решение но оно не удачное ...

Answer (score 0):

Смог сделать НО он добавляет окно по кругу от чего приложение начинает тянуться ...Походу Единственное решение это только через событие слушателя 
а вот и моё решение

```
var infowindow = [];

infowindow[i]=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow[i].setContent(locations[i][0]);
infowindow[i].open(map,markers[i]);
```